# I'm looking for USB-C to USB-C cable that is 10ft long

Tags: usb, cable

To charge my Pixel XL.  The supplied cable is too short for my needs.  USB-C to USB-A is viable but I'd need a compatible fast charge adapter as well.  I'm not seeing a whole lot of availability in the 10 foot range, at least not anything from well known manufacturers.

Can anyone recommend a 10 foot USB-C to USB-C cable for a Pixel XL?

OR

Can anyone recommend a 10 foot USB-C to USB-A cable and compatible fast charge adapter for a Pixel XL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At 9 (I know...it's not 10...) feet the [**AmazonBasics USB Type-C to USB Type-C 2.0 Cable**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GGKZ3MM) should be a great option.

officially supports fast charging (and some pixel owners confirm in the Q&As, and has a 5-star rating from Google Engineer and famous USB Type-C reviewer Benson Leung.